# 'there' vs 'it' expletive insertion

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, chomsky, x-bar-theory

These are my conditions for detecting an expletive position:

- if spec IP has been assigned non 'null' Case and is not theta marked.

However, after this I struggle to choose between 'it' and 'there'.

I read that 'it' takes a CP associate and 'there' takes an NP associate. I need to implement this in code and don't understand the logic to detect the associate (to clarify, one doesn't need to know code to answer the question, they only need to understand the logic given an x-bar tree).

This is in context of 'The Minimalist Program' by Chomsky, and 'Government and Binding Theory' by Haegeman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in my answer to another question of yours, the 'association' between 'dummies' and their 'associates' is **chain-formation**: 'dummy *it*' a) has no valued Thematic role feature, but b) it has a valued Category feature(= CP), c) a valued Case feature (nominative, when it occurs in subject position, objective, as in *I expect **it** to be clear that I am just a beginner*, or oblique, as in *You can depend on **it** that I mean no harm at all*), and d) a valued Number feature (always singular), so its associate must be an argument with 1) a valued theta role feature, 2) a valued (and compatible!) Category feature (= CP), 3) a compatible Number feature (= singular), and 4) NO valued Case feature (or the chain *{It-CP}* vill violate the Case Filter). That automatically excludes any 'associate' except a CP with a valued theta role and NO Case assigned to it, which, in practice, solves your problem in all cases.

As to 'dummy *there*', it has a) a valued Category feature (= DP/NP), b) a valued Case feature (nominative, when it is a subject, but alternatively objective, as in *I expected **there** to be some sort of celebration*, or oblique, when it follows a P, as in *I was fed up with **there** never being anybody to talk to*), c) no valued Number feature, and d) no valued Theta Role feature, either, which, in practice, also solves your problem in all cases: the 'associate' can only be a) a DP, b) it must have a valued Number feature (since, otherwise, *there* will not inherit it and the *{there-DP}* chain will not be able to 'agree' with the tensed V), c) it must have a valued Theta Role feature (or, again, the argument chain *{there-DP}* will lack a Theta Role and the Theta Criterion will be violated), and d) it cannot have a valued Case feature (or, in association with 'there', which already has its own valued Case feature - nominative, accusative, or oblique - the chain *{there-DP}* will have **two** valued Case features and will violate the 'Case Filter'). Again, such requirements in practice determine the only possible 'associate' of 'dummy' *there* in all cases: the associate must be a singular or plural DP with a theta role, but **cannot** be the complement or the specifier of **any** Case-assigning category (i.e., neither the complement of V or P, nor the specifier of T or D). That leaves you with specifiers of V, P, or A and with complements of non-Case assigning V's or A's, and, as no sentence will contain more than one **accessible** item of any of such classes, in practice, your problem vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

http://people.umass.edu/bhatt/lin380l/380l-f01-l11-12.pdf

This seems to answer most of my questions.